# Cómo puedo agregar la fecha actual a un Formulario Reactivo como placeholder?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular7, angular6

Hola estoy tratando de agregar la fecha actual como placeholder a un formulario reactivo, lo quie quiero es que cuando el usuario ingrese tenga la fecha actual por defaul y no el formato que me regresa el type="date", mi input se ve asi `<input type="date" [placeholder]="currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [ngModel]="fecha"... >` mientras que en mi archivo de TS

```
public currentDate: Date = new Date();
```

Pero sin embargo no se muestra en mi formulario, es correcto usar mi variable en un placeholder o deberia usarla como `[value]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Por qué haces mención de un formulario reactivo y usas binding directo con `ngModel`?

Tienes que instanciar un `FormGroup` para que realmente sea un formulario reactivo.

```
[placeholder]="currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
[value]="currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
```

Esto es correcto, debería funcionar, pero te dejo otra solución más limpia y manipulable.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tu',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <input type="date" [value]="currDate" [placeholder]="currDate" formControlName="fecha">
    </form>
  `,
})

export class TuComponent implements OnInit {

    // Prepara tu formulario
    form: formGroup;
    currDate: string;

    // Inyecta el pipe de fecha
    constructor( private dp: DatePipe ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // transforma el objeto date a una fecha de tipo string
        this.currDate = this.dp.transform( new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd' );

        // Crea un formulario reactivo y agrega un control, el valor por default será la fecha
        // que convertiste antes
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            fecha: new FormControl( this.currDate, [ Validators.required ] )
        })
    }
}
```

En tu archivo `.module.ts` debes inyectar también `ReactiveFormsModule` y `FormsModule` así como en el arreglo de `providers` inyectar `DatePipe`

Esta es la forma de construir un buen formulario reactivo.